# Threadpool Python future in a celery job appears to be blocking

Tags: python, celery, concurrent.futures

this is python 3.9 and Django 3.2, running in docker.

I'm trying to run a pool of futures in a celery job, where the pool is a ThreadPool.
I allow 50 workers, which is more than enough.
Celery is running in a docker container.
The futures are created in a loop. The loop reads a number of pages from a rate-limited API, and writes data to a table. The future calls a CPU-intensive process to work on the data just updated.

The first time, it works. The future is submitted and execution moves to the top of the loop immediately: the future runs concurrently.

But after the first iteration, I see behaviour I don't understand. Using time-stamped log messages, execution of the main loop suspends until the future is completed, for 8 to 15 seconds of wall time.
Adding log messages at the end of the future task show this is definitely the case. As soon as the future finishes, the main loop starts again.

the threadpool is created at the top of the celery task.

```
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50)
```

the future is submitted and saved:

```
f = pool.submit(self.cpu_intensive_task, job_id=job_id,
                                location_filter=location)
list_of_futures.append(f)
```

and the next loop iteration begins.

Later, I do:

```
 wait(list_of_futures, timeout=60)
```

Although the behaviour looks like something is waiting for the future to complete, it is not the problem.

If a threadpool runs out of threads, would it behave like this? The submit always succeeds immediately.

Comment: Have you tried using `return_when=ALL_COMPLETED` in your wait(), so that it does not wait until timeout actually runs out?

Comment: the problem of the main thread stopping happens way before the code ever gets to the wait(). I have no doubt at all about this. Whatever I do the wait won't matter. If I had another wait hiding invisibly after the submit which only activated after the first iteration of the loop, then I would have an explanation. However, I will add what you recommend.

Comment: If you could compile a sanitized version of what you exactly do, then it would be a bit easier to understand i guess. :)

Comment: Yes, I will try to make a minimal example of it. I suspect this is due to some interaction with running in Celery. The strangest thing is that it works correctly for the first future, but not ever again.

Comment: It works perfectly when run outside of Celery.

Comment: Ah. My celery pool option was gevent. This does not play well with threadpools. When using prefork, it works.

Answer (score 1):

When running celery with `pool=gevent`, ThreadPoolExecutor seem to block.

Using `pool=prefork` or `pool=threads` works.